# how to get the id from script to php file

Tags: php, jquery

```
PHP file:
<?php   
require_once('dbconfig.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM booking_table ";

$events = mysqli_query($link, $query);
?> 


script file:
function authentication1()
    {
        var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        var id = localStorage.getItem("id");

        if(token==null)
    {
        alert('Please Login To Continue');
        window.location="/";
    }
    else
    {   
        $.post("logoutchk.php", 
        {
            token: token
        },
        function(data, status)
        {   
            $("#checklogout").html(data);

        });
    }

    }
```

how to get the id which is taken from localstorage from script to php file...........................................................................................

Comment: Change `{ token: token }` to `{ token: token, id: id }` ? If not then I don't understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: Its tough to tell from the way you worded this what you are trying to do but what is seems is you are trying to send info you pull via JS to a php file. I would use Jquery/Ajax to send it to the PHP file.

Comment: thanks @IncredibleHat.